# Can't msdeploy web package to temporary folder?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msdeploy

We've got an Asp.Net web application we're trying to get pseudo-deployed to a folder, and I'm starting to think Microsoft are crazy -- why is it so hard to get a WAP to do a "Local FileSystem" deploy as part of MSBuild?

I can build with this:

```
msbuild .\SubSite.csproj "/p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release" /t:Package
```

And get a nice package.zip which I can deploy to a website...

However, I have two projects in my solution, which I need to combine before I ship them, so I want to deploy both packages into a folder, and then re-package that folder. Despite the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569019%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) on technet [to the contrary](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569034%28v=WS.10%29.aspx), it doesn't seem to be possible to do:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=.\SubSite.zip -dest:contentPath=.\Www\SubSite
```

Because you get the error:

> **Source (sitemanifest) and destination (contentPath) are not compatible for the given operation.**

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I could web deploy two sites inside one another without manually copying files out of a "PackageTmp" folder?  I mean, I'm aware that I could just [skip zipping the package and manually copy the files out](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild) to do this, but I'm not happy about having to create a custom target, and there's no other way to find that  just to do something that should be built in.

Comment: Indeed, an answer here (even if it's "That's not possible") would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did eventually figure out how to do this, but I'm not really happy about it ;-)

Basically, (as mentioned elsewhere on so), you can call msbuild with the target set to _WPPCopyWebApplication.  You can also specify/override the WebProjectOutputDir property when you do that.  Something like this (where ${name} are variables we're using)

```
msbuild ${SourcePath}\Www\UI\UI.csproj "/p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release;WebProjectOutputDir=${OutputPath}\AppRoot" "/t:_WPPCopyWebApplication"
msbuild ${SourcePath}\Www\Mobile\Mobile.csproj "/p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release;WebProjectOutputDir=${OutputPath}\AppRoot\Mobile" "/t:_WPPCopyWebApplication"
msbuild ${SourcePath}\Www\Service\WebService.csproj "/p:Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release;WebProjectOutputDir=${OutputPath}\AppRoot\WebServices" "/t:_WPPCopyWebApplication"
```

We can then package up the whole "AppRoot" in a separate step.